# Need ideas about OPTIMIZE TABLE

Tags: mysql, optimization, delete

Looking at a database with 10 tables and fairly active at by-the-hour changes. On the first of each month, I purge some rows from 3 tables to remove outdated material and keep the size down. All of these tables show highlighted (red) 'Overhead' in phpMyAdmin.

Given these conditions, should the tables be `OPTIMIZED` just after the purge. If not a good idea, why? (The purge occurs at lowest usage time of day.)

Let's say the tables and current (mid-month) Data & Index sizes are:

```
          Rows     Deleted     Data      Index

table1   17,000     7000      4.3 MiB    1.2 MiB    Holds +300/day Transaction Info
table2    6,000     1000     25.5 MiB    231 KiB    Holds User Schedule Info
table3    1,800       30      297 KiB     43 KiB    Holds User Info
```

This question is in response to learning about indexes and efforts to reduce slow queries and learning about high counts for:

1. Handler read rnd next
2. Handler read prev
3. Created tmp disk tables
4. Opened tables

In reading articles about these items, it seems to be a 'learned' science and requires testing.

Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Your tables are incredibly small. You should be able to run

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE table1, table2, table3;
```

very quickly.

Looking at the statistics in your question

- [Handler_read_rnd_next](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Handler_read_rnd_next) : The number of requests to read the next row in the data file. This value is high if you are doing a lot of table scans. Generally this suggests that your tables are not properly indexed or that your queries are not written to take advantage of the indexes you have.
- [Handler_read_prev](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Handler_read_prev) : The number of requests to read the previous row in key order. This read method is mainly used to optimize ORDER BY ... DESC.
- [Created_tmp_disk_tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Created_tmp_disk_tables) : The number of internal on-disk temporary tables created by the server while executing statements. If an internal temporary table is created initially as an in-memory table but becomes too large, MySQL automatically converts it to an on-disk table. The maximum size for in-memory temporary tables is the minimum of the tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size values. If Created_tmp_disk_tables is large, you may want to increase the tmp_table_size or max_heap_table_size value to lessen the likelihood that internal temporary tables in memory will be converted to on-disk tables. You can compare the number of internal on-disk temporary tables created to the total number of internal temporary tables created by comparing the values of the Created_tmp_disk_tables and Created_tmp_tables variables.
- [Opened_tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Opened_tables) : The number of tables that have been opened. If Opened_tables is big, your table_open_cache value is probably too small.

If these global status variables present a problem after running `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, this is usually a strong indicator that you have to improve the design of your queries and the size of certain caches.

Comment: Do you see a problem with optimizing the tables monthly? (Thanks for the statistic tips.)

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, there IS work to be done with queries, indexes and cache. I'm NO expert. :)

Comment: @David - In more than a decade, I have seen 2 MyISAM tables and 0 InnoDB tables that would benefit from periodic `OPTIMIZE`.  And those needed it only monthly.  This is from looking at thousands of slow queries on hundreds of servers.