# How to lower "Created_tmp_disk_tables" - temporary tables count created on DISK?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a ubuntu, mysql 5.6 DB that is heavy used by thousands of users. After 10 days of running I have this values:

```
| Created_tmp_disk_tables | 894170 |
| Created_tmp_files       | 26068  |
| Created_tmp_tables      | 914511 |
```

My config values are:

```
| tmp_table_size | 268435456 |
| max_heap_table_size | 1073741824 |
```

when I had tmp_table_size = 16MB and max_heap_table_size=16MB it was the same. Than I changed it to tmp_table_size = 256MB and max_heap_table_size = 1GB but Created_tmp_disk_tables did not stop growing. The rate is exactly the same.

I have 26GB heap. All tables are INNODB.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

What do you mean by a "26GB Heap"?

`tmp_table_size = 256M` is dangerously high.  If multiple connections decide to need tmp tables, you could run out of RAM.  Swapping is *worse* for performance than lowering various settings.

Tmp tables are *necessary* in many situations.  Don't fear them.  But do check on them.

`DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `UNION` often *require* a tmp table.  If the tmp table fits in `min(tmp_table_size, max_heap_table_size)`, then the tmp table *may* be in RAM using `Engine=MEMORY`.  If bigger than that, then the tmp table is `Engine=MyISAM` and is slower.  There are other reasons for using MyISAM, most notably is selecting a `TEXT` field.  [More details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-temporary-tables.html).

Another common "error" is to blindly use `VARCHAR(255)` and utf8.  When using MEMORY, that becomes a 765-byte `CHAR`, which hastens the conversion to MyISAM.

The numbers you gave...

- Created_tmp_disk_tables is nearly as large as Created_tmp_tables -- This implies that either `tmp_table_size` is not big enough (which I doubt), or MEMORY cannot be used (which I suspect).  Above 20% is a red flag in my analysis.
- Created_tmp_tables / Uptime -- above 20/second is a red flag
- Created_tmp_disk_tables / Uptime -- above 1/second is a red flag
- Created_tmp_disk_tables / Questions -- above 4% is a red flag

Set long_query_time = 1 and turn on the SlowLog, preferably to FILE.  Wait a day, then use pt-query-digest on the slowlog to find the "worst" queries.  If you can't figure out how to improve them, ask us.

I'll disagree with Rolando on two items:

- RAM disk is a bad idea -- it is better to give the extra RAM to other caches rather than trying to outsmart MySQL.
- `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is rarely useful, and not very relevant for the question.

Comment: With the "rate" unchanged after increasing those settings -- This implies that setting were already plenty big.

Comment: Lovely answer! I didn't know that DISTINCT and GROUP BY will necessitate the creation of temporary tables. On a high traffic website, we currently have "Created_tmp_disk_tables / Uptime" as 5.35. The load on the server is ideal though, but it could be even better if that problem is addressed.

Comment: @itoctopus - If you can identify the main query causing the tmp tables, start a new question with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  We may have a quick fix.

Comment: @RickJames, you mention in your answer "...or MEMORY cannot be used (which I suspect)". What would cause a table to be written to disk instead of in-memory assuming `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` are of sufficient values? I'm experiencing the same thing, high on-disk temp tables despite having large values for both the settings above.

Comment: @RyanGriffith - There are two cases for switching to MyISAM:  (1) certain restrictions (`TEXT`, etc) (there is a manual page on such), and (2) exceeding either `..._table_size` setting (after trying to use MEMORY).  There are too many possible _cures_ to try to list them here.  So let's look at your case -- open a Question with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: [_when MEMORY can't be used_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) (and other notes).

Answer (score 1):

If the rate is exactly the same, then you have some query or configuration  tuning to do. Why ?

I have discussed tweaking [tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) and [max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) before

- `Nov 25, 2014` : [Increase performance WITHOUT adding indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83528/increase-performance-without-adding-indexes/83538#83538) (RAM Disk Discussion)
- `Feb 06, 2014` : [MariaDB: Created_tmp_disk_tables high after start](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58325/mariadb-created-tmp-disk-tables-high-after-start/58328#58328)
- `Apr 18, 2013` : [Need ideas about OPTIMIZE TABLE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40388/need-ideas-about-optimize-table/40391#40391)

You may have to look into ramping up [join_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size) and [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) (Look at my second post)